# Is it necessary to unsubscribe a real-time connection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, real-time, stomp

I'm working on a notification implementation with `StopmJs` in `React`. I subscribe two destinations in order to get the number of new messages and list of messages.

Does it lead to memory leak if I don't unsubscribe the destinations and instead listen to them constantly?

In the network tab everything seems OK, and I request only once.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to two different functions is okay, but you have to be careful how the subscription is implemented. If the subscribing makes a new subscription every time you call `subscribe()` method you will have a memory leak. For example you will have memory leak everytime your component rerenders if you are subscribing to a function in a `useEffect()` like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  eventListener.subscribe();
}, [])
```

but this is easily fixed by destroying the subscription between re-renders using the [cleanup function](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1) in useEffect.

example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  eventListener.subscribe();

  return () => eventListener.unsubscribe();
}, [])
```